# Get list of shared calendars through Google Calendar API

Tags: methods, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client, google-workspace

I want to get a list of **shared** (not primary or resource) Calendars through Google Calendar API for PHP. I tried the following:

```
(...)
$service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);
(...)
$calendarList = $service->calendarList->listCalendarList();
```

I get three types of results in Array/Object

[id] => code@subdomain.domain.ext

- Primary Calendar, username@domain.ext
- Shared Calendar, code@group.calendar.google.com
- Resource Calendar, code@resource.calendar.google.com

These are only distinguishable by their $key (id) and I could filter Shared Calendar by $value "group.calendar.google.com" however I think this can be done with more clean coding or by using a built-in method.

Is there any other way **to only get** Shared Calendars?

Comment: if it's not mentioned in the documentation, which, as far as I can see, it's not, then probably not, unfortunately. Not everything is exposed by the API

Comment: @ADyson. Thanks for your answer. But is there any other way to distinguish a shared calendar from a resource calendar? It seems that only the ID is different

Comment: As I already said, no. The relevant info is just not exposed through the API as far as I can see. Nothing in https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList or https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendars looks relevant to me, unless possibly the "kind" property on the calendar object gives it a way - what does that return? I think it probably just returns "calendar" every time, but maybe worth checking.

Comment: @ADyson [kind] => calendar#calendarListEntry